# blade pagination start data page 0 label 1 using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination

I'm using blade pagination for my project.

The pagination is working fine.

Now I want to make like,

1. The **data-page** should start from **0,1,2,3...** And the **label** should 
   starts from **1,2,3,4...**

Jquery script

```js
    $.fn.bladePagination = function(options) {
     if(typeof(options) === 'object' || typeof(options) === 'undefined') {
      var settings = $.extend({}, $.fn.bladePagination.defaults, options);
      return this.each(function() {
       var jqPagination = $(this);
       if(jqPagination.hasClass('slice-pagination')) {
        createPagination(jqPagination, settings);
        initPageClick(jqPagination, settings);
       }
      });
     }
    };
       
    /*==============================================
     * default options
     *==============================================
     */
    $.fn.bladePagination.defaults = {
     maxPageNum: 5,
     firstLabel: '|&lt;', // |<
     prevLabel: '&lt;',   // <
     nextLabel: '&gt;',   // >
     lastLabel: '&gt;|',  // >|
     moreLabel: '...',
     rebuildAfterClick: false,
     clickPage: function(page, jqPagination) {}
    };
    
    /*==============================================
     * private functions
     *==============================================
     */
    var createPagination = function(jqPagination, settings) {
     var currPage = Number(jqPagination.attr('data-current'));
     var totalPage = Number(jqPagination.attr('data-total'));
     var pageShowArray = new Array();
     
     //first page number changed into zero
     pageShowArray.push({
      type: 'page first' + ((1 == currPage) ? ' disabled' : '')
      , page: 1
      , show: settings.firstLabel
     });
     
     //previous page
     pageShowArray.push({
      type: 'page prev' + ((1 == currPage) ? ' disabled' : '')
      , page: (currPage <= 1) ? 1 : (currPage - 1)
      , show: settings.prevLabel
     });
     
     //page number
     var pageNumArray = new Array();
     var leftPageNum = (settings.maxPageNum - 1) / 2;
     var rightPageNum = settings.maxPageNum - 1 - leftPageNum;
     if(currPage - leftPageNum < 1) {
      for(var i = leftPageNum; i > 0; i --) {
       var page = currPage - i;
       if(page < 1) {
        rightPageNum ++;
       } else {
        pageNumArray.push(page);
       }
      }
      pageNumArray.push(currPage);
      for(var i = 1; i <= rightPageNum; i ++) {
       var page = currPage + i;
       if(page > totalPage) break;
       pageNumArray.push(page);
      }
     } else {
      for(var i = rightPageNum; i > 0; i --) {
       var page = currPage + i;
       if(page > totalPage) {
        leftPageNum ++;
       } else {
        pageNumArray.unshift(page);
       }
      }
      pageNumArray.unshift(currPage);
      for(var i = 1; i <= leftPageNum; i ++) {
       var page = currPage - i;
       if(page < 1) break;
       pageNumArray.unshift(page);
      }
     }
     if(pageNumArray[0] > 1) {
      pageShowArray.push({
       type: 'more'
       , page: -1
       , show: settings.moreLabel
      });
     }
     for(var i = 0; i < pageNumArray.length; i ++) {
      var pageNum = pageNumArray[i];
      pageShowArray.push({
       type: 'page' + ((pageNum == currPage) ? ' active' : '')
       , page: pageNum
       , show: pageNum
      });
     }
     if(pageNumArray[pageNumArray.length - 1] < totalPage) {
      pageShowArray.push({
       type: 'more'
       , page: -1
       , show: settings.moreLabel
      });
     }
     
     //next page
     pageShowArray.push({
      type: 'page next' + ((totalPage == currPage) ? ' disabled' : '')
      , page: (currPage >= totalPage) ? totalPage : (currPage + 1)
      , show: settings.nextLabel
     });
     
     //last page
     pageShowArray.push({
      type: 'page last' + ((totalPage == currPage) ? ' disabled' : '')
      , page: totalPage
      , show: settings.lastLabel
     });
     
     //create page
     jqPagination.empty();
     for(var i = 0; i < pageShowArray.length; i ++) {
      var pageShow = pageShowArray[i];
      var html = '<li class="' + pageShow.type + '" data-page="' + pageShow.page + '">' + pageShow.show + '</li>';
      jqPagination.append(html);
     }
    }
    
    var initPageClick = function(jqPagination, settings) {
     var jqPageSet = jqPagination.find('li.page');
     
     //event handler
     jqPageSet.off('click');
     jqPageSet.click(function() {
      var jqPage = $(this);
      if(! (jqPage.hasClass('active') || jqPage.hasClass('disabled'))) {
       var page = jqPage.data('page');
       settings.clickPage(page, jqPagination);
       
       if(settings.rebuildAfterClick) {
        //rebuild
        createPagination(jqPagination, settings);
        initPageClick(jqPagination, settings);
       }
      }
     });
    }
```

I want to change something here

```
    var html = '<li class="' + pageShow.type + '" data-page="' + pageShow.page + '">' + pageShow.show + '</li>';
```

I'm using some other library to get images, there the image value start from 0, In that library i can't able to make changes.

i want like this to start like this below

```
<li data-page='0'>1</li>
<li data-page='1'>2</li>
<li data-page='2'>3</li>
```

Comment: assuming `pageShow.show` is what actually *shows* the page number to the user, why not use `pageShow.show + 1`?

Comment: @Scaramouche It should start <li data-page='0'>1</li>

Comment: so, that's exactly what I proposed, notice to only add 1 to `pageShow.show`, not to `pageShow.page`, got it?

Comment: @Scaramouche already 'pageShow.page' and "pageShow.show" starting from '1' .Now what i want is 'pageShow.show' should start from '1' and 'pageShow.page' should start from '0'

Comment: well, maybe I understood wrong, I thought they were starting at 0, well if they are starting at 1, subtract 1 from `pageShow.show`, look, it should go like this: `var html = '<li class="' + pageShow.type + '" data-page="' + (pageShow.page-1) + '">' + pageShow.show + '</li>';`

Comment: @Scaramouche i will check

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var html = '<li class="' + pageShow.type + '" data-page="' + pageShow.page + '">' + (parseInt(pageShow.page)+1) + '</li>';
```

May be it will work for you.

Comment: Try this : var html = '<li class="' + pageShow.type + '" data-page="' + pageShow.page + '">' + (parseInt(pageShow.page)+1) + '</li>';